# How to set SMART goals for a sports performance skill that is hard to measure

Tags: tennis, technique

I have been reading 'Building a Tennis Champion' and they talk about setting SMART goals.  For the specific part they use an example of measuring first serve percentage.  That is obviously something that is relatively easy to measure and so I can create a SMART goal listed as: "Improve first serve percentage by 10% from 40% to 50% in 6 months.

But I also want to work on some biomechanical items.  For example, in tennis I overuse my arm and want to  change my technique so that I am using my legs and hips more to hit the ball.  This is not so easy to measure?  How can I make a SMART goal for this goal?  Or do I just have to observe my body and measure how I think I am hitting?

Comment: This appears to be a combination of personal planning and fitness development skills question, than about a specific competitive sport. For the latter it would be better on Physical Fitness SE, but the former has no directly relevant site to my knowledge. In any case, is this a question that would only be about tennis, or is tennis merely a placeholder sport?

Comment: How did you determine that you overuse your arm?

Comment: @PhilipKendall If you don't use your body, and overuse just the arm, reliability of shot suffers.  I found this via video.  Are you suggesting video and check that way?

Comment: That would seem to be one way, yes. The real point is that you had some way of determining _THING_ in the first place, whatever _THING_ may be, so you can use the same method again to determine if _THING_ has improved. "Measurable" doesn't have to be "quantitative".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal doesn't have to be *in competitive play*, it can also be a goal *in practice/training*.  Using the provided example:

> Spend 30 minutes per day for 4 weeks doing simple hits from a ball machine where I focus on leg/hip motion driving the power to the hit.

Specific, Measurable, Time-bound, at least.